# Can an ethernet cable on a reel be used at full speed?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable

I bought 100m of relatively cheap CAT6 FTP ethernet cable on a reel. For testing purposes, I installed RJ45 jacks on the ends to check whether it can be used at 1Gbps. Observing the lights on the switch revealed that the link fails at 1Gbps a few times and after a short while, it falls back to 100Mbps. At that speed the link seems to be reliable.
Is it possible that the same cable would work at 1Gbps when used in a straight line without the reel which introduces some inductance?

Comment: Good cable loosely coiled will not impede or slow down the signal. Tightly coiled cable might slow down the signal.  I think it should be OK but not certain. Cheap cable (poor twisting of conductors) could affect signal speed. Only way to test is lay it out and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try replacing the RJ45 jacks to ensure they were properly installed. Poor jack installation could cause a speed problem.

Good cable, loosely coiled (by hand), with good terminations will not slow down the signal. I have seen this done in some installations.

Closely wound cable (reel) should not be an issue but I am not 100% certain. 20 cm outside reel diameter is probably OK

Cheap cable could be an issue.  Top cable speed requires highly quality mechanical twisting of the conductors to reduce inter-conductor capacitance.

In your case, you may need to lay the cable out to get an accurate test.

I think I have provided enough information, so you may wish to return if not satisfied and purchase better quality cable.

Comment: thanks for your answer! The diameter is ~20cm outside and ~5cm inside. Does this qualify as "loosely coiled"? I wanted to avoid laying it out because of the returns policy of the merchant.

Comment: On a reel, cable is usually closely wound, so tight. By loosely coiled, I mean hand coiled. I added to my answer to help clarify.